# How to parse command-line arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line

How to effectively parse this command line in C++?

```
program -parameter1=value1 -parameter2=value2 -parameter3=value3
```

How to effectively drop a combination of the parameter and value

```
-parameter=value
```

I am trying to use this code but it does not work properly:

```
parameter[256], value[256],
while ( --argc > 0 )
{
   if ( *argv[argc] == '-' )
   {
       for ( char * text = argv[argc]; ; )
       {    
            switch ( * ( ++ text ) )
            {
                case '=' :
                {
                   *value = *(  text );
                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                   *parameter = *text;
                }
            }
         }

       //Testing parameters and values
    }
}
```

Thanks for your comments and improvements.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work properly? Does it fail to tell the parts of each command apart from each other? For example i don't see, how value should be filled because you always access its first byte, the same with parameter.

Comment: As Mark B answers, I heavily suggest the use of library code to parse arguments. It might _look_ easy, but there are actually gazillions of corner cases to handle.

Comment: Your code looks like C. Are you really willing to use C++ constructs ? String processing is really different in C and in C++.

Comment: `value[256]` cries for buffer overflow.

Answer (score 16):

Did you consider `boost::program_options` or if you can't use boost, `getopt_long`?

Comment: This is probably a good answer as long as you don't have to include a thousand other boost files as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've leveraged TCLAP ( [Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/) ) in many C++ based command line apps and been very happy with it, but it might not give you all the flexibility to read the parameters in the format you are looking at, but still worth a look ,[boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/program_options.html) is a good suggestion also.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a lot more transparently with `std::string` and functions like `find_first_of`, splitting off the different parts and have the nice bonus that each time a find function returns `std::string::npos`, you know you've got an invalid argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use the standard C library for argument parsing : there is a premade function called getopt for that.

Comment: getopt is not a part of the standard C library. It's a part of the POSIX standard though.

Answer (score 0):

`*value = *(  text );` This line only writes one character.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [flag library in coost](https://github.com/idealvin/coost/tree/master#31-flag).

```
// xx.cc
#include "co/flag.h"
#include "co/cout.h"

DEF_bool(x, false, "x");
DEF_uint32(u, 0, "xxx");
DEF_string(s, "", "xx");

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    flag::parse(argc, argv);
    cout << "x: " << FLG_x << '\n';
    cout << "u: " << FLG_u << '\n';
    cout << FLG_s << "|" << FLG_s.size() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Define flags with **DEF_xxx** macros, and call **flag::parse(argc,argv)** at the beginning of the main function.

Build the above code as **xx**, run it as follow:

```
./xx
./xx -x=true -u=77 -s="hello world"
./xx -x -u 88 -s kkk
```